# Call python script from another script and get a specific value

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to get the BPMS of an WAV file:
https://github.com/scaperot/the-BPM-detector-python/blob/master/bpm_detection/bpm_detection.py

I'm trying to call this script from my own script but since bpm_detection.py just printing (and not returning anything) I can get the bottom line value:

`print 'Completed.  Estimated Beats Per Minute:', bpm`

I tried to edit bpm_detection.py script by adding a main() function that I can call. But it mess something up and bmp resulting in Nan:

```
def main(filename, window):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process .wav file to determine the Beats Per Minute.')
    parser.add_argument('--filename',
                    help='.wav file for processing')
    parser.add_argument('--window', type=float, default=3,
                    help='size of the the window (seconds) that will         be scanned to determine the bpm.  Typically less than 10 seconds. [3]')

    #args = parser.parse_args()
    samps, fs = read_wav(filename)
    print ("testing")
    #print (fs,samps)

    data = []
    correl = []
    bpm = 0
    n = 0
    nsamps = len(samps)
    print ("nsamps")
    print(nsamps)

    window_samps = int(window * fs)
    print ("window, window samp")
    print (window, window_samps)
    print ("fs")
    print (fs)

    samps_ndx = 0  # first sample in window_ndx
    max_window_ndx = nsamps / window_samps
    print ("max_window_nds")
    print (max_window_ndx)

    bpms = numpy.zeros(max_window_ndx)
    print ("bmps")
    print (bpms)

    # iterate through all windows
    for window_ndx in range(0, int(max_window_ndx)):

        # get a new set of samples
        # print n,":",len(bpms),":",max_window_ndx,":",fs,":",nsamps,":",samps_ndx
        data = samps[samps_ndx:samps_ndx + window_samps]
        if not ((len(data) % window_samps) == 0):
            raise AssertionError(str(len(data)))

        bpm, correl_temp = bpm_detector(data, fs)
        if bpm == None:
            continue
        bpms[window_ndx] = bpm
        correl = correl_temp

        # iterate at the end of the loop
        samps_ndx = samps_ndx + window_samps;
        n = n + 1;  # counter for debug...

    bpm = numpy.median(bpms)
    print('Completed.  Estimated Beats Per Minute:', bpm)
    return bpm
```

As you could see, I added a lot of print to debug it. It seems that all the values are fine up until the following line where max_window_nds is getting 0.0:

```
max_window_ndx = nsamps / window_samps
print ("max_window_nds")
```

printing both nsamps and window_samps resulting in:
6195200 and 333333

So I'm failing to find what am I doing wrong. My final goal is to find a way to get bmp variable.

Comment: Did you try `max_window_ndx = float(nsamps) / float(window_samps)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually need to access the variable directly or can you still parse what the script you're calling actually prints? Because you can always use `subprocess` module to call another script.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python','-u','bpm_detection.py',
    'arg_to_bmp_detection.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

prints_out = p.communicate()
```

If you want something fancy (like a progress bar wrapper), use a thread to async process the output while your main program does something to wait for the subprocess to finish: [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Comment: What is PIPE? I'm getting a name error for it. Thanks!

Comment: subprocess.PIPE sorry

Comment: It's not the best approach I was hoping for but with some regular expression, I were able to get the needed value. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The code in `bpm_detection.py` is written for Python 2, you can spot this at the final print statement. You are using Python 3 (can also be seen from your use of the print function.
Another thing which has changed from Python 2 to Python 3 and which you have to port is the division operator `/`. In Python 2 if both operands are integer it means integer division. In Python 3 it is always returning a float. You have to check all divisions if an integer division was intended and then use Python 3 integer division operator `//`.
Note, that this may not the only thing to port to Python 3.

Comment: I indeed forgot to mentioned I convert the script from Python 2 to Python 3. I tried to change division operator to // but it still results in 0 instead of 0.0

Comment: Note, that porting this code is not for the faint of heart, if you don't know the involved mathematics.

Comment: @Yakir Mordehay: Double check. From the values you give in the question the result should be `18`.